# Video player crashes running video in WhatsApp on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: 8.1, whatsapp, video, lumia-540, crash

My Microsoft Lumia 540 running Windows 8.1 has issue with WhatsApp. WhatsApp application crashes after running any video 2, 3 seconds.

I have tried re-installing Windows 8.1, tried restarting the phone, updating video player and whatsApp application, but in vain.

Although Windows 10 runs WhatsApp better but Windows 10 has its own issues on Lumia 540, the most important one is running the whole phone very slow.